# How to get rid of keys and values ​while leaving some keys and values ​in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_user] => 2112100001
            [nik] => 3216060611900007
            [nama] => Jauharuddien Sofari
            [tempat_lahir] => Klaten
            [tanggal_lahir] => 1995-12-21
            [jk] => L
            [id_agama] => 1
            [no_telp] => 081123123123
            [alamat] => elapa dua wetan jakarta
            [tanggal_masuk] => 2020-11-03
            [gaji_pokok] => 4500000.00
            [id_role] => SPV
            [score] => 0.5
            [created_at] => 2021-12-10 09:46:25
            [created_by] => 2112010001
            [update_at] => 2022-01-07 21:00:19
            [update_by] => 2201050001
            [id_department] => 1
            [nama_department] => Quality Control
            [id_jabatan] => 1
            [nama_jabatan] => Supervisor
            [status] => 4
            [total_overtime] => 6
            [val_overtime] => 4
            [val_workexp] => 2
            [val_age] => 2
            [val_salary] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_user] => 2112100008
            [nik] => 3216060611900014
            [nama] => Biantono
            [tempat_lahir] => Jakarta
            [tanggal_lahir] => 1982-12-08
            [jk] => L
            [id_agama] => 1
            [no_telp] => 081123123123
            [alamat] => Pasar rebo
            [tanggal_masuk] => 2020-02-12
            [gaji_pokok] => 5000000.00
            [id_role] => SPV
            [score] => 0.29
            [created_at] => 2021-12-10 10:07:35
            [created_by] => 2112010001
            [update_at] => 2022-01-07 21:00:19
            [update_by] => 2201050001
            [id_department] => 4
            [nama_department] => Human Resource
            [id_jabatan] => 1
            [nama_jabatan] => Supervisor
            [status] => 4
            [total_overtime] => 6
            [val_overtime] => 4
            [val_workexp] => 2
            [val_age] => 4
            [val_salary] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_user] => 2112100005
            [nik] => 3216060611900011
            [nama] => Agung Nugroho
            [tempat_lahir] => Yogyakarta
            [tanggal_lahir] => 1985-07-31
            [jk] => L
            [id_agama] => 1
            [no_telp] => 081123123123
            [alamat] => Jl. raya jababeka 2 no.112
            [tanggal_masuk] => 2008-09-10
            [gaji_pokok] => 6000000.00
            [id_role] => SPV
            [score] => 0.28
            [created_at] => 2021-12-10 10:00:56
            [created_by] => 2112010001
            [update_at] => 2022-01-07 21:00:19
            [update_by] => 2201050001
            [id_department] => 4
            [nama_department] => Human Resource
            [id_jabatan] => 5
            [nama_jabatan] => Foreman
            [status] => 4
            [total_overtime] => 7
            [val_overtime] => 4
            [val_workexp] => 4
            [val_age] => 4
            [val_salary] => 4
        )
)
```

And I just need to take some keys but keep it in the same structure. like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [val_overtime] => 4
            [val_workexp] => 2
            [val_age] => 2
            [val_salary] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [val_overtime] => 4
            [val_workexp] => 2
            [val_age] => 4
            [val_salary] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [val_overtime] => 4
            [val_workexp] => 4
            [val_age] => 4
            [val_salary] => 4
        )
)
```

How to do it?

I have tried to extract the values ​​manually in a loop like this:

```
foreach ($arr_result_all as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {

    }
}
```

But I'm stuck, I don't know what to do again in the 2nd iteration..

Please help, thank you very much for any help

Comment: It would seem simpler to change the query to only return the columns you actually want rather than the whole row :)

Comment: It might also be useful to keep one or two of the other fields that identify who did this overtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a similar but slightly different solution

```
$newArr = array();
$targetKeys = array("val_overtime","val_workexp","val_age","val_salary");
foreach($arr_result_all as $d){
  $newAssoc = array();
  foreach($targetKeys as $key){
     $newAssoc[$key] = $d[$key];
  }
  $newArr[] = $newAssoc;
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: thanks for the logic, I don't know how to loop an array with key names yet..